# type-casting of session object to type object(class) in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

i have college's faculty data in **Session["FacultyData"]** session.

i cannot get data in Faculty class's object from this session.

i have tried following code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (dbDataContext dt = new dbDataContext())
        {
            if(Session["FacultyData"]!=null)
            {
                Faculty objFac = new Faculty();
               objFac = (Faculty)Session["FacultyData"];
            img1.ImageUrl = objFac.Photo;
            txtIDNo.Text = objFac.UserId;
            txtName.Text = objFac.FacultyName;

.

.
```

there is an `InvalidCastException` with message that **Unable to cast object of type "System.Data.Linq.DataQuery'1[Faculty]' to type 'Faculty'**  at line :

objFac = (Faculty)Session["FacultyData"];

Comment: Session["FacultyData"] is a descendant of `IEnumerable<T>`, not `Faculty`. You will have to do use `Session["FacultyData"].FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Your session variable holds the query itself, not the result of the query.

Comment: where are you setting `Session["FacultyData"]` ? lets cut down on the guessing game for others..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be setting the Session["FacultyData"] value from a Linq query. The Linq queries use deferred evaluation, so instead of the result of the query, you are storing the query itself in the session variable. You need to use an operator on the Linq query that forces it to evaluate, like ToList, ToArray, or FirstOrDefault. Then store the resulting query result object in the session.